# How to register a custom URLStreamHandlerProvider in an application server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, wildfly, application-server

With a standalone application I can register an `URLStreamHandlerProvider` via the service loader. But this does not work with a war file in an application server like Tomcat or WildFly.

The alternate solution via `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory( x )` does also not work. Only one can call this and the application service has already do it.

The third hack via reflection no longer works with Java 17.

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static java.util.Hashtable java.net.URL.handlers accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module
```

Are there other solutions inside an application to register an URLStreamHandlerProvider? For example via web.xml or Servlet API? Are there individual solutions for single application server?

Comment: What problem would this help solve *in an app server*?

Comment: You likely need to add `opens java.net` to your `JAVA_OPTS`.

Comment: @nitind You ask for which function you need a URLStreamHandlerProvider?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins This is not possible within the war file. Telling each client what changes to make is very error-prone.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the client is ran in WildFly, then you'd simply modify the `JAVA_OPTS` in the `standalone.conf` file and it would open the `java.net` module. If you're creating a new JVM for clients, then you'd need to pass that argument to the new JVM.

Comment: This are not my WildFly servers. This are the servers of the customers. I develop only the *.war file which the customer deploy in its application server. The servers can be different products and different product versions. That I need a standard solution which I can use inside the *.war file.